# bash IFS awk $2

Tags: bash, awk, ifs

How can I use `IFS` and `awk` `$2` value on the same line?

ex.

```
array=(
  element:5001
  element:5002
  element:5003
  element:5004
)
IFS=':'
for i in "${array[@]}"
  do
  set -- $i

  part1=$1
  part2=$2

  cd $part1
  # this following line is where I am having the issue.
  # $2 equal to part2 from the string split, but the $2 to be
  # awk value for $2
  echo "$(ps aux | grep '[s]omething --port '$2'' | awk '{print $2}')"
  # use part2 later in code
done
```

Presently, I am only able to use `$2` from `IFS` split.

Note: I have seen post about using the `-v` option with `awk` but I believe that is when you want to set a value to run against awk.  I would like to print `$2` generated from `awk`.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean. Can you show an example of what you're trying to print?

Comment: What's the point of `echo`? `echo "$(command)"` is the same as just running `command`.

Comment: The `awk` command is in single quotes, so it shouldn't process `$2` as a shell variable, it will be treated as an `awk` expression.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should do what you want.

Comment: You can't put single quotes within single [quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). And `$i` within single quotes is not going to be substituted for the variable value.

Comment: I have a an array strings that represent a part of a path and a port.  I need to iterate through threw that array matching against another sting appended with the port.  I put echo, just to print it out, but I am trying to kill the process.  I am curious however, how you use `$2` for the `IFS` context as well as the `awk` context.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for that link.  `Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar and @l0b0.

I need to fix my quotes.

```
...
echo $(ps aux | grep '[s]omething --port '$2 | awk '{print $2}')
...
```